# Newton's law of cooling, soup

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, exponentiation

Newton's law of cooling states that the temperature $T(t)$ of an object at time $t > 0$ changes at a rate proportional to the difference between the temperature of the object and the temperature $T_S$ of its surroundings, provided that this difference is not too large. That is, $T(t)$ satisfies

$\quad T'(t) = k (T(t) - T_s)$

where k is a constant.

Suppose that the temperature of a cup of soup obeys Newton's law of cooling. If the soup has a temperature of $\; 190^\circ\, F$ when served to a customer, and 5 minutes later has cooled to $\; 180^\circ\, F$ in a room at $\; 72^\circ\, F$, how much longer must it take the soup to reach a temperature of$ \; 135^\circ\, F$?

Answer (1) in additional minutes = ?

If the same cup of $190^\circ\, F$ soup is instead placed into a freezer set at $30^\circ\, F,$ what is the time required for the soup to cool from $190^\circ\, F to 135^\circ\, F$ in this situation?

Answer (2) in minutes = ?

--

After watching the tutorial on the [Cooling Law](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IICR-w1jYcA), I tried to use formula:

$ T(t) = T_{surrounding} - Ce^{-kt}$ (general formula for cooling?)

$C = (T - T_s)$

$T(t) = 72 - 118e^{-kt}$ (for my case)

To find k:

$180 = 72 - (190-72) \cdot e^{-k \frac{5}{60}}$

$180 = 72 - 118e^{-k \frac{1}{12}}$

$ k = -12 \cdot ln(\frac{-54}{59})$

Then to get answer to (1):

$135 = 72 - 118e^{-kt}$

$ 135 = 72 - 118e^{12 \cdot ln(\frac{-54}{59}) \cdot t}$

$ t = \frac{ln(\frac{-63}{118})}{12 \cdot ln(\frac{-54}{59}) \cdot t} $

But that's not the correct answer!

I then tried a different formula to get answer to (1):

$T(t) = (T - T_s) e^{kt} + T_s$

$T(t) = 118e^{kt} + 72$

$180 = 118e^{k \cdot 5/60} + 72$

$k = 12 ln(\frac{54}{59})$

But even with this k value I get the wrong answer, why?

And yes, I absolutely have to assume that t should be in hours format.

Comment: How do you know the answer you received is wrong? In the first approach you got the signs wrong (note that when you substitute $t=0$ you don't get the initial temperature you want). But the second approach looks fine (note that you did get $k<0$ as should be for cooling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, in newton's law of cooling, the temperature $T(t)$ is assumed to be decreasing with respect to the time hence, rate of change of temperature $T'(t)=\frac{dT}{dt}$ is taken as negative hence we have the following equation of cooling $$T'(t)=-k(T(t)-T_s)$$
$$\frac{dT}{dt}=-k(T-T_s) \implies \frac{dT}{(T-T_s)}=-kdt$$
$$\int \frac{dT}{(T-T_s)}=-k\int dt$$ $$\ln(T-T_s)=-kt+C$$$$\implies T=e^{-kt+C}+T_s\tag 1$$

Now, setting $T(t)=\text{initial temperature}=T_0$ at $t=0$, we get $$T_0=e^{0+C}+T_s\implies C=\ln(T_0-T_s)$$
Hence, setting the value of $C$ in (1), the equation of cooling is given as 
$$kt=\ln\left(\frac{T_0-T_s}{T-T_s}\right)\tag 2$$
$\color{blue}{\text{Given condition}}$: The temperature falls from $\color{red}{(T_0=\color{blue}{190^\circ\ F})\to (T=\color{blue}{180^\circ\ F})}$ in time $\color{red}{t=\color{blue}{5\ minutes}}$ at room/surrounding temperature $\color{red}{T_s=\color{blue}{72^\circ \ F}}$ hence setting all the values in (2), we get 
$$k(5)=\ln\left(\frac{190-72}{180-72}\right)\implies k=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{5}\ln\left(\frac{59}{54}\right)}$$
Now, the time $t$ required to fall temperature from $\color{red}{(T_0=\color{blue}{190^\circ\ F})\to (T=\color{blue}{135^\circ\ F})}$ hence setting all the values in (2), we get 
$$t=\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{190-72}{135-72}\right)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{5}\ln\left(\frac{59}{54}\right)}\ln\left(\frac{118}{63}\right)$$ $$t=\frac{5\ln\left(\frac{118}{63}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{59}{54}\right)}\approx \color{red}{\color{}{35.43\ minutes}}$$
Now, the time $t$ required to fall temperature from $\color{red}{(T_0=\color{blue}{190^\circ\ F})\to (T=\color{blue}{135^\circ\ F})}$ at surrounding temperature $\color{red}{T_s=\color{blue}{30\circ \ F}}$ (placed into a freezer) hence setting all the values in (2), we get

$$t=\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{190-30}{135-30}\right)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{5}\ln\left(\frac{59}{54}\right)}\ln\left(\frac{32}{21}\right)$$ $$t=\frac{5\ln\left(\frac{32}{21}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{59}{54}\right)}\approx \color{red}{\color{}{23.78\ minutes}}$$

Comment: Since there is a constant factor in the conversion and since we are only dealing with temperature differences in this question (so the fact that the zeros of the two scales are different doesn't really matter) you should be able to work with Fahrenheit just as well (The value of $k$ will be different of course, but the results for $t$ should be the same).

Comment: you are absolutely right. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot Uhm, Did you get this: $kt=\ln\left(\frac{T_0-T_s}{T-T_s}\right)\tag 2$ by moving ln(T0−Ts) to the right side, and then according to ln rules, lnx - lny = ln(x/y)? Also why do you plug in 5 as t? Shouldn't it be in hours format? 5/60? Also, why do you have positive kt? I mean it seems like the right formula, but you had negative -kt on the right side (1)?

Comment: Notice, $-ln(a/b)=\ln(b/a)$. initial condition is given that the time taken is 5 minutes so we take $t=5$. you can use the time in hour the result will be same. positive $kt$ does not have any particular significance it's just for simplification of calculations. Negative sign has been eliminated by reversing in logarithms (ln) as follows $$-kt=\ln\left(\frac{T-T_s}{T_0-T_s}\right)\implies kt=\ln\left(\frac{T_0-T_s}{T-T_s}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is better to set exponent  negative ( factor k positive) so  no error would occur in sign as happened here.

$ \quad T'(t) = -k (T(t) - T_s)$

After all, it is not heating..

Also

$$ (T(t)- T_s)  =  (T_{hot}-  T_s)  e^{- k t } $$

$$ {- k\,t }= log_e \dfrac  { T(t)- T_s} { T_{hot}-  T_s}    $$

which helps to calculate constant $k$

Answer (score 0):

$\dot T=k(T_s-T)$
$\dot T=k(72-T)$
$\dot T+kT=72k$
Homogeneous solution
$T_h=Ce^{-kt}$
Particular solution
$T=72$
General solution, by superposition
$T=72+Ce^{-kt}$
$T_0=T(0)=190$
$190=72+Ce^{-k(0)}$, $C=118$
$180=72+118e^{-k(5)}$, $k=(1/5)ln(59/54)$
Now we can write the solution
$T=72+118e^{-(1/5)ln(59/54)t}$
And for $T=135$
$135=72+118e^{-(1/5)ln(59/54)t}$
We find $t=35.43$ min
Now, answer (1), the additional minutes are
$35.43 - 5.00 = 30.43$ min

For answer (2):
$\dot T=k(30-T)$
$\dot T+kT=30k$
Homogeneous solution
$T_h=Ce^{-kt}$
Particular solution
$T=30$
General solution, by superposition
$T=30+Ce^{-kt}$
$T_0=T(0)=190$
$190=30+Ce^{-k(0)}$, $C=160$
$k$ is a constant already found: $k=(1/5)ln(59/54)$
Now we can write the solution
$T=30+160e^{-(1/5)ln(59/54)t}$
And for $T=135$
$135=30+160e^{-(1/5)ln(59/54)t}$
We find $t=23.78$ min