# What will be the temperature of the object at t = 2 minutes?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An object is removed from a room where the temperature is 69 degrees and is taken outside, where the air temperature is 30 degrees.  After 1 minute, the temperature of the object reads 53 degrees.  What will be the temperature of the object at t = 2 minutes?

Is that new-code application 
Is we use $\frac{dT}{dt}=-k(T-T_O)$...is i am right can any help me

Comment: That looks right. Hint: for what function is $f'(t) = f(t)$?

Comment: @Alexis Olson....sorry i did't get can help to sovle

Comment: There are tons of related questions for this. Try searching for Newton's Law of Cooling or look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449149/newtons-law-of-cooling-soup?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The object's initial temperature is $T(0)=69^{\circ}$
The outside temperature is $T_e=30^{\circ}$
After one minute the temperature is $T(1)=53^{\circ}$
We want to find what will the temperature be after two minutes: $T(2)=?$

The general solution is: $\hspace{10 mm}T(t)=T_e+(T_0-T_e)e^{-kt}$;$\hspace{15 mm}T(t)=30+39e^{-kt}$

So: $\hspace{10 mm}T(1)=30+39e^{-k}=53$;$\hspace{20 mm}e^{-k}=\frac{23}{39}=\lambda$

And$\hspace{10 mm}T(2)=30+39e^{-2k}=30+39\lambda^{2}=30+39(\frac{23}{39})^{2}=43.56^{\circ}$